# How can I convert something to double?

Tags: java, double

I have an object from an implemented class `ReportManager`. Now `getReport()` is a number like 0.23 with the data type `report`. But I want this number to be a double so I can work with it.

I cannot change the class, because it is implemented in the Java compiler (it is for writing macros for a program).

Does anybody have a suggestion how I could handle it? I checked the API and there is no function implemented that could help me.

**EDIT**: I do have the situation: I want to calculate the Center of Pressure of an object in my simulation. So I need the moment in that position to be 0.
Now: This is how the automated macro ask the value of the Moment:

```
MomentReport momentReport_0 =
      ((MomentReport) simulation_0.getReportManager().getReport("Moment 1"));
```

Now I want to take the abs of it, because I don't mind if it's positive or negative.

```
while(Math.abs(momentReport_0) > 0.2)
```

(Do iterate and change position.) At the end I want to println the the position.

`simulation_0` is an object of `Simulation`. I could copy a part of the API if it's needed. Just don't know which class documentation would help.

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence "I cannot change the class, because it is implemented in the Java compiler (it is for writing macros for a program)."? Can you either share ReportManager's source or link to its javadoc so we can see what you're asking about?

Comment: Yeah, that would make it easier to understand the return type of `getReport()`. If the return type is a custom class `report`, it would totally depend on the implementation of that class how you could convert it to a double.

Comment: It is very vague what you want to achieve and what your current situation is. Can you provide more information. The very least would be the return value of the getReport() (which i assume is object from your description). In general if you are dealing with Objects that can be everything the only way would be going by reflection (switch case instaceof) and then react correctly by cast/convert/parsing.

Comment: added my situation to the description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the number to a `double` so that you can work with it, assuming it's returning you a single-precision float at the moment.

```
double result = (double) reportManager.getReport();
```

I recommend you read up on what typecasting is so that you can better understand what's going on here, as there would be some situations where it's unsafe to cast:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Comment: You might want to read up on type conversion yourself. If it indeed returned a float, there would be no need to cast since it's a widening conversion. `double d = 1.0f;` works, but `float f = 1.0d;` doesn't.

Comment: @Kayaman, in which case, does that imply that the '0.23' that ChrizZly is getting is not represented as a float?

Comment: Not directly at least. I'd wager that `toString()` gives him at least a `0.23` value somewhere, but since he's not sharing more information, it's a useless question so far.